# Title page with the author name on the top left corner

Tags: titles

I'm having difficulties to create a page title for my research paper which require this format:

The first page (the top left corner) should contain the full name of the author(s). In the center of the page the title of the paper should be printed in capital letters (double-spaced if more than one line). An abstract and a list of key words in English should be printed below the title. A footnote with the address of the institution of each author as well as the e-mail address should be printed below.

The article class produce the author name below the title. Can anyone assist me on this?

Comment: You should take a look at the `titling` package documentation. It has a number of tools for such things.

Comment: Alternatively, don't use \maketitle at all.  Just format the page.

Comment: [How to construct a title page?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-add-a-flyleaf-code/210280#210280)

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    \begingroup\flushleft
    Jane Doe\footnote{Anonymus Institut, forget Street,
        Neverland, \url{jane@doe.com}}\\
        Donald Duck\footnote{Ducktown
            \url{donald@duck.org}}\par
    \endgroup
    \vfill
    \begingroup
    \centering
    \doublespacing
    \Large
    \MakeUppercase{%
    This is the Title of your beautiful Research Paper}\par
    \endgroup
    \vfill
{\bfseries Keywords:} Ducks, research, dixie dancing\bigbreak
{\centering\bfseries Abstract\par}\smallbreak
\blindtext
\end{titlepage}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```